# Get value from querystring AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, parameters, query-string

From url i want get number 5. My url is index.html?ID=5

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $location, $http) {
  alert("Account Number  is - " + $location.search()['ID']);
```

Alert return 5 after load but my URL change to index.html?ID=5#/index.html?ID=5

how solve this problem, I don't need change url.

Comment: Do you use router in your app?

Comment: what would console.log($location.search()['ID']) gives you?